# permanent-id-based hyperlinking scheme for Web HTTP/HTTPS, how many ways can it be done?

Tags: http, namespaces, hyperlink, resolution

**Background:**

Suppose I have a website that is hosted on http://www.example.com and the site has a *lot* of absolute internal links. Something happens that requires me to move the *entire* website to http://www.example.net with all other things remaining the same.

Obviously, I can do a global search and replace on the website code to fix this, but what I am wondering is how many ways can I create a *permanent* linking scheme that will never break regardless of what site I move to, as long as the relative paths are the same.

**NOTE:** replace example.com and example.net with the names of two totally different web-hosting companies. They were just used for generic names that do not provide free advertising.

**Question:**

How many different ways are there to support permanent hyperlinks such as:

```
http://some-aribitrary-string.com/some/path/here/page.htm
```

Such that:

- some-arbitrary-string represents a unique string that will never have to change
- some-arbitrary-string resolves to the DNS entry or IP address of whatever machine my code happens to be hosted on at any given time
- if and when I have to change servers, I only have to update this information in one place (instead of having to do global string search and replace)
- in order to use this scheme I do not have to have access to DNS records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Rewrite should be enough:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://some-arbitrary-string.com/$0 [L]
```

You could additionally use `[P]` or `[R=301]` to route requests through an internal proxy or properly redirect them.